# Fast string or JSON look up data structure

Tags: python, json, performance, dictionary

If I have a huge number of strings, would the fastest way to look them up and grab the value be a dictionary? When I mean huge, I mean potentially 2000 strings each of length 500 (JSON).

`dict1 = {"JSON1": "JSON1", "JSON2": "JSON2", "JSON3": "JSON3", ... }`

So let's say I am trying to see if `JSON2` is in `dict1`. Would `dict1["JSON2"]` be the fastest way to see if `JSON2` exists in `dict1`? Remember, I am dealing with a lot of data and lengthy strings that represent JSON.

Comment: Is the `json` implementation included with Python not fast enough?

Comment: @SimeonVisser should i convert my keys to JSON objects? or leave them as strings?

Comment: `dict` lookups are O(1).  And `'JSON2' in dict1` would be the literal code to check if the string `'JSON2'` exists in your dict.

Comment: @roippi I know that lookups are O(1) but it's just the size of the dictionary will be big (~2000) and also the keys are essentially very long strings. I was wondering if this was the best I can do

Comment: @Liondancer you can do better, but do you need to do better? 2000 is really not that much honestly... there are faster implementations for the parsing for the strings, but is that what's holding you back?

Comment: Neither 2000 nor 500 are large numbers so I think the standard implementation should be fast enough (you haven't told us for what purpose you're looking at the performance).

Comment: @SimeonVisser I have never dealt with so much data before so I am assuming this is a lot. I guess it isn't haha That is why I wanted to increase the performance as much as possible

Comment: Agree with @SimeonVisser - wouldn't call this a 'large' set of data at all.

Comment: I've had several million keys in a dict before without any noticeable side-effect other than my RAM weeping salty tears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the key and value are both the same string.

If you're just wanting to check presence, you don't need to waste the reference to the key.  In that case, you can use a set.

Otherwise, a dict in RAM is the best you're going to get in Python.  If you have something bigger than RAM (doesn't sound like it), there's ZODB or a full-blown database.

Answer (score 3):

Use a dict. Unless you've run out of RAM, it's likely the solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only looking to test for membership then perhaps a set is what you want?

```
data = set(["JSON1", "JSON1", "JSON2"])
```

Gives you a set with

```
{"JSON1", "JSON2"}
```

Then

```
"JSON2" in data
True
```